# Trying to get Last day of hijri year Resulting in conversion error My query attached

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, sql-server-2012, hijri

i am trying to get last day of hijri calender,

First i am defining my queries and logic,
This query getting my hijri dates.

```
SELECT top 1 convert(date,dateHijri,103) , datepart(year,try_convert(date,dateHijri,103))
from Item
```

it gives me result,

```
1440-07-19 , 1440
```

This query getting last date of georgian calender,

```
 select top 1 DATEADD(MILLISECOND, -3,DATEADD(YEAR, DATEDIFF(YEAR, 0, GETDATE()) + 1, 0)) 'Last Day of Georgian Year'

Result :  2018-12-31 23:59:59.997
```

Now, my final query in which i am trying to get last day of hijri year try to merg first and second query,

```
select top 1 DATEADD(MILLISECOND, -3,DATEADD(YEAR, DATEDIFF(YEAR, 0, convert(date,dateHijri,103)) + 1, 0)) as 'Last Day of Hijri Year'  from Item 

Error:The conversion of a date data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.
```

hopes for your suggestion thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this

```
select top 1 DATEADD(MILLISECOND, -3, CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(VARCHAR(4), YEAR(convert(date,dateHijri,103)) + 1)+'0101', 131)) as 'Last Day of Hijri Year'  from Item
```

Comment: How to use the same query for start date ?

Comment: you can use this for the first day `CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(VARCHAR(4), YEAR(convert(date,dateHijri,103)) )+'0101', 131) as 'First Day of Hijri Year' `